# TreeTableView selection contains null values after source change

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview, easybind

A list of basic values is filtered by a (changing) predicate. The `FilteredList` is mapped to `TreeItem`s and this resulting list is then used as the root `TreeItem`s children.

When a selection was made on the `TreeTableView` and afterwards the predicate changes, accessing the selected items results in a `NullPointerException`.

It seems to me that items contained in the change are `null`. Is there a design flaw in this coarse concept?

This does **not happen** for the classes `TreeView` and `ListView`.

I tried to produce a MCVE using https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind for the mapping:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.fxmisc.easybind.EasyBind;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    // fields protect bound lists from GC
    private ObservableList<DataItem> itemizedDataPool;
    private FilteredList<Data> filteredDataPool;
    private ObservableList<Data> selectedData;

    static class Data {
        final int value;

        public Data(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    static class DataItem extends TreeItem<Data> {
        final Data data;

        public DataItem(Data data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        List<Data> dataPool = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            dataPool.add(new Data(i));
        }

        filteredDataPool = new FilteredList<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataPool));

        TreeTableView<Data> listView = createTreeTableView();
        Spinner<?> lowerBoundSelector = createLowerBoundFilter();
        Label sumLabel = createSummarizingLabel(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

        Parent root = new VBox(listView, lowerBoundSelector, sumLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 768, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TreeTableView<Data> createTreeTableView() {
        itemizedDataPool = EasyBind.map(filteredDataPool, DataItem::new);
        TreeItem<Data> itemRoot = new TreeItem<>();
        Bindings.bindContent(itemRoot.getChildren(), itemizedDataPool);

        TreeTableView<Data> listView = new TreeTableView<>(itemRoot);
        listView.setShowRoot(false);
        itemRoot.setExpanded(true);
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        listView.getColumns().add(new TreeTableColumn<>("Data"));
        return listView;
    }

    private Label createSummarizingLabel(ObservableList<TreeItem<Data>> selectedItems) {
        Label sumLabel = new Label();
        selectedData = EasyBind.map(selectedItems, (TreeItem<Data> t) -> ((DataItem) t).data);
        selectedData.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (Data d : selectedData) {
                    sum += d.value;
                }
                sumLabel.setText("Sum: " + sum);
            }
        });
        return sumLabel;
    }

    private Spinner<Integer> createLowerBoundFilter() {
        Spinner<Integer> lowerBoundSelector = new Spinner<>(0, 20, 0, 1);
        lowerBoundSelector.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                filteredDataPool.setPredicate(t -> t.value > lowerBoundSelector.getValue());
            }
        });
        return lowerBoundSelector;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well last time I checked the `ListIterator.nextIndex` method of a ListIterator somewhere in of those lists returned by the selection model was broken (don't know if they have checked my bug report and fixed that error). This could be the source of the error.

Comment: @fabian Do you have a link to this bug report?

Comment: Bug report: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8145887 Unfortunately they won't let me comment on this (or at least I haven't found out how to...), since I've identified the source: compare the indices used by `next()` and the index returned by `nextIndex` here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java#ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.SelectionListIterator.nextIndex%28%29

Comment: Yes, this is indeed wrong. `nextIndex` should return `pos` directly, as it always points to the "next" index. But I don't see a trivial connection between this bug and the bug I'm dealing with. As noted in the text, my problem only occurs for `TreeTableView`s and not for `TreeView`s or `ListView`s. The above code does work perfectly for the latter two classes.

Comment: `TableViewSelectionModel` extends `MultipleSelectionModel` which uses `ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

`TreeTableView` uses `TreeTableViewArrayListSelectionModel`, which extends `MultipleSelectionModelBase`, which uses `ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList`, which uses (and contains) `SelectionListIterator`, which has a broken implementation for its method `nextIndex`.

Thanks to [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778430/treetableview-selection-contains-null-values-after-source-change/35795113#comment59240083_35778430) for pointing that out.
He also filed a bug report (http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8145887).

## Workaround

Using a buffer in between could provide an effective workaround for the problem above. I tried several approaches. `setAll` on selection invalidation and `Bindings.bindContent` **do not work**. In both cases I received `null` values in the list. The straightforward "solution" is to simply filter the `null`s out. This leads to the inefficient but apparently effective code below.

```
// [...]
TreeTableView<Data> listView = createTreeTableView();
selectionBuffer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        selectionBuffer.clear();
        for (TreeItem<Data> t : listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            if (t != null) {
                selectionBuffer.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
});
// [...]
```

Using `selectionBuffer` instead of `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` should now compensate the implementation problem in `nextIndex`.